# Can't scroll in UIScrollView as soon as UILabel / other subview added in Storyboard

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, storyboard, uilabel, scrollview

I encountered the following problem: as soon as I add e.g. a UILabel to my UIScrollView - using the storyboard - the scroll view stops "working" (with that I mean you cannot scroll at all). However adding a subview programmatically the scroll view works fine but since I prefer designing my apps visually with storyboard I would like to solve this mysterious error.

Does anyone knows why this error is occurring? Thanks in advance :)

PS: I do set the contentSize of my scrollView, so this cannot be the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the code in the viewDidAppear function like this

> -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
>
> ```
> [super viewDidAppear:animated];
> self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500.f, 500.f);
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This is the correct answer. But I would like to dig further deeper. WHY ? Thanks